# Multiple JS file in html not working. Only one works

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have a problem with some JS files.
I have linked my JS files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/epos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/newRep.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/printLabelCustomer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addNewWork.js"></script>
```

The problem is that only this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/printLabelCustomer.js"></script>
```

but if I put, for example, the contents of "js/newRep.js" inside "js/printLabelCustomer.js" all works fine.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What your dev tool is saying ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: In the browser's console there aren't any errors, I'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Please may you explain what you mean by "using visual studio code"?

Comment: Is the dev tool that I'm using

Comment: Consider opening the page in a web browser and looking there? - How are you running the code within VS Code?

Comment: Try putting all the script tags after closing `body` tag.